# Make multiple additions with multiple input value Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I am creating a lot of numbers inside of a div. Each time someone clicks a number I want to add it to another div. Let me make myself clear with some examples:

When a user clicks on the `add` class, the value of `.addcop` should be added to the value of `.totalyHide`. That means the value should change to `12`.

When I click on the `.add2` the value should be added on to `12`, so the value of `.totalyhide` becomes `32.80`.

and other terms, if I click the first + and click the second +, they should be added together on Yearly Price.
I hope you understand what I am trying to do.

```js
$('.add').click(function() {
  $('.addcop').click();
  var dp = $(".addcop").val();
  var total = $(".totalyHide").val();
  var bigTotal = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(dp);
  $(".totaly").val("$" + bigTotal);
});
$('.add2').click(function() {
  $('.procurement').click();
  var procurement = $(".procurement").val();
  var total = $(".totalyHide").val();
  var bigTotal = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(procurement);
  $(".totaly").val("$" + bigTotal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="box box6">
  <div class="titlet">work on it
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="explain">to help you better</div>
  <div class="money">
    <p class="me">$12 Yearly</p><i class="add fas fa-plus-square fa-2x"></i></div>
  <input type="text" name="content" class="addcop" style="display: none;" value="12">
</div>
<div class="box box5">
  <div class="titlet">Procurement
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="explain"></div>
  <div class="money">
    <p class="me">$20.80 Yearly</p><i class="add2 fas fa-plus-square fa-2x"></i></div>
  <input type="text" class="procurement" style="display: none;" value="20.80">
</div>
<div class="box box8">
  <div class="total">Your First Deposit will be: <input class="total1" type="button" value="$546"></div>
  <input type="text" class="totalHide" style="display: none;" value="546">
  <div class="total">Yearly Price: <input onchange="myFunction()" class="totaly" type="button" value="$0"></div>
  <input type="text" class="totalyHide" style="display: none;" value="0">
  <div class="total">On-off Price: <input class="total" type="button" value="$546"></div>
  <input type="text" class="total" style="display: none;" value="546">
</div>
```

Comment: zcoop98, yes. They are clickable. I want when I click the first + and click the second +, for 12 and 20.80 to be added together on Yearly Price.

Comment: I understand now :) At the moment, clicking the `+` *replaces* the value instead of adding it, which is what you're looking for.

Comment: You're adding the value of `.totallyHide`, which is `0`. Maybe clicking on `.addcop` should update that value?

Comment: BTW, if you want inputs that the user doesn't see, use `type="hidden"` rather than `style="display: none;"`

Comment: zcoop98, I am glad you understand me.

Comment: Barmar, I didn't see that. Thanks. I did that, It works when I click on .addcop the value has been updated. But what I wanted to do is when I click on procurement for the values to add together. like 12 + 20.80

Comment: Isn't that what `parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(procurement)` does?

Comment: Kind of, but Try to run the code and you will see what's happening At the moment, clicking the + replaces the value instead of adding it, which is what you're looking for. Bu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a minor issue with the JQuery code that you have written. You can add the following changes to get the desired result.

```
$('.add').click(function() {
  $('.addcop').click();
  var dp = $(".addcop").val();
  var total = $(".totalyHide").val();
  var bigTotal = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(dp);
  $(".totalyHide").val(bigTotal); // Add this line here
  $(".totaly").val("$" + bigTotal);
});
$('.add2').click(function() {
  $('.procurement').click();
  var procurement = $(".procurement").val();
  var total = $(".totalyHide").val();
  var bigTotal = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(procurement);
  $(".totalyHide").val(bigTotal); // Add this line here
  $(".totaly").val("$" + bigTotal);
});
```

The thing to note here is that whenever you are calculating the total,
you'll have to set that total to $(".totalyHide"), so that you can read the updated value upon next click.

Comment: Harshal Patil, that's awesome, But it's going to add the value even if you click it twice.

Comment: In that case you can set the values of addcop and procurement class to 0 respectively at the end of each click event.